# node.js nib coercion exception

Tags: node.js, nib, stylus

I'm running the project found here: http://clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus in Windows with VS2013 (after installing the VS plugin).
This project worked fine on linux (only 1 small change - replace "!!!5" in layout.jade with "doctype html").
On windows, i get an exception on node_modules\stylus\lib\nodes\node.js on coerce function: "cannot coerce !important to unit".

After investigating, I've found that "!important" is used because of the line dealing with border-radius in style.styl. If I comment out this line the exception doesn't occur but this prevents me from drawing borders.

Any ideas why does this happen?

Comment: Where is the !important mention on the linked blog post?

Comment: it is called within Stylus when parsing the "border-radius" option in style.styl